# Discover virtual machine on esxi with snmp

Tags: vmware-esxi, snmp

I want to discover all virtual machines directly on ESXi server (not by vcenter) with snmp.

I have correctly started snmp service and can through snmpwalk / snmpget tools.

I found this oid to get all virtual machines :

1.3.6.1.4.1.6876.2.1.1

But, I can't query this oid, snmp return :

> No Such Object available on this agent at this OID

Of course, ESXi (in 6.0.0 - 14513180 version) have virtual machines.

Why oid don't exist ?

Best regards,

Comment: Odd way of doing this, what if the VM FWs are blocking that port, or snmp's not running, or you had NSX doing microsegmentation, or you get responses from VMs not on the hosts you're looking at, or physical - not sure what you're trying to achieve here but it looks like a very odd way to doing whatever it is.

Comment: The objective: use Discover mode from opendcim software. This oid is present in php code in https://github.com/samilliken/openDCIM/blob/master/classes/ESX.class.php at line 40.